# readNetFromDarknet assertion error separator_index < line.size()

Tags: yolo, darknet

I am failing to use `readNetFromDarknet` function for the reasons I do not understand. I am trying to use `yolo3-spp` with this configuration file https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov3-spp.cfg.

```
import cv2
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet("../models/yolov3-spp.weights",  "../models/yolov3-spp.cfg")
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.5.4) /tmp/pip-req-build-3129w7z7/opencv/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_io.cpp:660: error: (-215:Assertion failed) separator_index < line.size() in function 'ReadDarknetFromCfgStream
```

Interestingly, if I use `readNet` instead of `readNetFromDarknet`, it seems to work just fine. Should I stick to using `readNet` instead and why `readNetFromDarknet` is not actually working?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in order function arguments. readNetFromDarknet waits first config file and second - weights. A readNet function [can swap arguments](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/685797f403db8e2e327f271ac7e1ab4833b91e7d/modules/dnn/src/dnn_read.cpp#L39) if they have a wrong order.
So right code:

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet("../models/yolov3-spp.cfg", "../models/yolov3-spp.weights")
```